# Лингвистический терроризм как объект внимания литературы

Tags: литература

Недавно здесь почему-то вдруг стала очень популярна тема лингвистического терроризма, или, как его еще ошибочно, на мой взгляд, называют, лингвистического фашизма или грамматического нацизма. В этой связи меня посетила мысль о том, что эта тема обладает потенциалом для раскрытия в литературе сатирического жанра. Однако, осуществив поиск литературных реализаций этого потенциала доступными мне средствами, я нашла только вот это [сочинение сатирической направленности](http://matukhnov.ru/wp-content/uploads/2011/11/Учись-учиться.jpg), [плод трагического восприятия мира](http://atkritka.com/upload/iblock/cde/atkritka_1349516820_444.jpg), ну и [настоящий шедевр](http://gl.weburg.net/00/fck/nazii.jpg). 
Нет ли столь же выдающихся, но несколько более значительных по объему литературных произведений, посвященных данной теме?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Noir, вы знаете английский? Если да, могу дать ссылку еще на один шедевр.

Comment: >Noir, вы знаете английский?

Ну приблизительно так же, как и русский: знать не знаю, но ошибки исправлять люблю.

Comment: http://engsuccess.ru/english-grammar-nazi/

Comment: >http://engsuccess.ru/english-grammar-nazi/

Исступленные овации! Но предисловие к этой пьесе... http://s09.radikal.ru/i182/1408/48/1bf5200bfe30.jpg

Answer (score 4):

Я считаю, что этот термин придумали малолетки, которым лень учить русский язык. И вместо того, чтобы почитать учебник русского языка, проще, конечно, объявить тех, кто тычет их носом в собственное безобразие, граммарнаци.
Сейчас вообще время троллей и раздутых дураков и неучей, потому что раньше в реале им били морды за троллинг и травлю порядочных людей, а сейчас они отводят душу в интернете, где им морду набить, увы, не могут.

Answer (score 3):

В этом году в списке "Букера" была книга Валерия Вотрина "Логопед" - занятная лингвистическая антиутопия.

Из описания в Сети:

> Дейст­вие романа разворачивается в государстве, управляемом законами орфоэпии. Умение следовать правилам пунктуации и орфографии определяет социальное положение граждан, а необходимость контролировать их соблюдение создает развитую систему надзорных и регулирующих органов. Два главных героя романа — логопед, встроенный в государственную систему надзора за языковыми нормами, и журналист, высланный за несообразные с языковой политикой суждения. Одному суждено разрушить государст­венную систему изнутри. Другой станет последней надеждой на сохранение языка страны и, как следст­вие, ее государственности.

Comment: Антиутопия?! [Опять-таки](http://s09.radikal.ru/i182/1408/48/1bf5200bfe30.jpg).

Answer (score 3):

У Акунина в "Соколе и Ласточке" секретарь-секретарша Николаса Фандорина, чтобы скрыть свою безграмотность писал(а) записки исключительно на "олбанском". Это если реакцию на граммарнаци вспомнить.

Граммарнаци в искусстве тоже представлены. Базаров в "Отцы и дети", профессор Преображенский в "Собачьем сердце", В фильме "Доживём до понедельника" есть сцена, где герой довольно резко отчитывает учительницу за неправильное слово.

А уж книг, где граммарнаци поучают как правильно говорить и писать вообще не счесть.

Вообще, вежливый человек - это не тот, кто не прольёт соус сам, а тот, кто не заметит, как это сделал другой. Того, что мы знаем плохо, гораздо больше того, что мы знаем хорошо. И кичится своим знанием перед другими право не стоит, хотя и хочется.

Answer (score 0):

Позволю себе привести уже упоминавшуюся на этом сайте [ссылку](http://smixer.ru/news/a-181.html). По-моему, претендует на шедевр.

Comment: Ну, хорошо, действительно, — шедевр. А как насчет произведений художественной литературы? Причем не обязательно сатирических — юмористические даже предпочтительнее.

Comment: Я тут поразмышляла над словами одного из героев этой драмы и пришла к выводу, что, если парень утверждает, будто, когда придет время, неучи всем стадом примутся блеять «расия впирёт» — это достаточно благоприятный прогноз по сравнению с другими возможными. Я боюсь, что ближе к реальности в конечном итоге окажутся те, кто прогнозирует, что блеять они начнут «роисся вперде!»... Да... они начнут блеять, а нам, господа, останется это констатировать.

Comment: @Noir, Вы слишком серьезно относитесь к этой статье. Если Вы еще не поняли, эта статья - шуточная, как и весь сайт. Почитайте другие новости с этого сайта и просто улыбнитесь.

Comment: Вот их дисклеймер: 


"Все персонажи и события наших новостей являются персонажами и событиями только наших новостей.

Привычная для новостных сообщений информационная составляющая в наших сообщениях отсутствует. Она заменена на литературно-творческую составляющую, основанную иногда на реалиях современного информационного поля.

Поэтому любое сходство с существующими в офлайне лицами и фактами — не более, чем обычное сходство.

Именно делать новости — наша профессия."

Comment: А в чем, по-вашему, проявилось мое серьезное отношение?